# R function changing a data set - and not returning it

Tags: r, function

I am wondering if it is possible in R to make a function that alters a data set and does not return it as a value. The reason is mainly because I am afraid of time difficulty of the issue on very large data sets. To get concrete - I have a function of type

```
f <- function(data, ...) {
  add several columns to data
  return(data)
}
```

This means that I need to call

```
data <- f(data, ...)
```

to update a dataset. Instead,  I would like to just call

```
f(data)
```

to update (add columns to) my data set.

I have two questions:

1) Is my assumption that the method I am using now will take a long time for very large data sets right? (Or will R somehow see, that I have just added columns?)

2) Is there a way to modify function to do what I have proposed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tested it with a real example and found that it takes too long? If performance and huge datasets are your problem then using `data.table` objects rather than a  `data.frame` is essential. Wasn't aware you could pass by reference in R but you could leve the data in the Global environment and still have access to it from a within a function.

Comment: Is not what `data.table` `:=` function is already doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as as I know and as commented by dickoa in your question, data.table should be already doing that: Check `?data.table` and then search for the link "help page for :=". This will explain how assignment by reference works with data.table.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your first question: just test it. I'll give an example below, but test it with your own code and your own data sets.

```
library(MASS)

data <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(1E6, mu=rep(0, 20), Sigma=diag(1:20)))
data2 <- data

add_columns <- function(data) {
  data$X <- rnorm(1E6)
  data$y <- rnorm(1E6)
  data
}
```

Test with function call:

```
> system.time({
+   data <- add_columns(data)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.567   0.000   0.568 
> system.time({
+   data <- add_columns(data)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.711   0.128   0.839
```

Without function call:

```
> system.time({
+   data2$X <- rnorm(1E6)
+   data2$y <- rnorm(1E6)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.650   0.020   0.669 
> system.time({
+   data2$X <- rnorm(1E6)
+   data2$y <- rnorm(1E6)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.589   0.024   0.613
```

The function call is slightly slower (perhaps), but the difference is so small that I would not bother to start messing around with global assignments or environments.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass by reference in R, but it is quite hard. See http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Pointers_passing_reference_.html or maybe the R.oo package.